# eth0 always has 192.168.1.1 and ignored a network with a DHCP server

Tags: linux, dhcp-server

Rarely my network interface (eth0) always has:

```
    $ ifconfig eth0
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:00:04:00:0a:04  
              inet addr:10.100.1.198  Bcast:10.100.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::a800:4ff:fe00:a04/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:300017 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:125399 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:131522946 (125.4 MiB)  TX bytes:13330040 (12.7 MiB)
              Interrupt:43 Base address:0x8000
```

and

```
    $ route -n
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
    169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

When I connect to a network where there is a DHCP server, all is OK and it give me 10.100.1.198 address and I have acces to the network but when I want to see my ip address always returns me: 192.168.1.1

What is happening?

---

UPDATED:
I use debian wheezy
And I have this:

```
    $ tree -L 2 /etc/network
    /etc/network
    ├── if-down.d
    │   ├── avahi-autoipd
    │   ├── bind9
    │   ├── openvpn
    │   ├── sendmail
    │   └── wpasupplicant -> ../../wpa_supplicant/ifupdown.sh
    ├── if-post-down.d
    │   ├── avahi-daemon -> ../if-up.d/avahi-daemon
    │   ├── bridge -> /lib/bridge-utils/ifupdown.sh
    │   ├── sendmail
    │   ├── vde2
    │   ├── vlan
    │   ├── wireless-tools
    │   └── wpasupplicant -> ../../wpa_supplicant/ifupdown.sh
    ├── if-pre-up.d
    │   ├── bridge -> /lib/bridge-utils/ifupdown.sh
    │   ├── ethtool
    │   ├── vde2
    │   ├── vlan
    │   ├── wireless-tools
    │   └── wpasupplicant -> ../../wpa_supplicant/ifupdown.sh
    ├── if-up.d
    │   ├── avahi-autoipd
    │   ├── avahi-daemon
    │   ├── bind9
    │   ├── ethtool
    │   ├── ip
    │   ├── mountnfs
    │   ├── openssh-server
    │   ├── openvpn
    │   ├── sendmail
    │   └── wpasupplicant -> ../../wpa_supplicant/ifupdown.sh
    ├── interfaces
    └── run -> /run/network

    5 directories, 29 files
```

Comment: Would help to know the distro, though I have a feeling one of your config files is setup wrong.

Comment: Agreed, my first instinct is to ask for the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`.

Comment: I use Debian wheezy.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh It's Debian, you'll want `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: Can you describe more: 'but when I want to see my ip address always returns me: 192.168.1.1'. How you access (see) your ip address, by running ifconfig again? So you are saying that your ifconfig is changing the addresses between two randomly?

Comment: I mean when I in a network 10.100.1.0/24 I still watching on my eth0 '192.168.1.1' address :| but I have access on the 10.100.1.0/24 network. When I startup/reboot my debian, the ip address of eth0 is of 192.168.1.0 network! :S when I not have configure the eth0 into /etc/network/interfaces (in that file I have configure only lo interface)